# Pra que serve a declaração 'let' em uma consulta LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, resharper

Eu tenho a seguinte consulta LINQ:

```
var source = from em in query
             select new
             {
                 Id = em.UniqueID,
                 Data = em.Data == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : em.Data.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm")                     
             };
```

A propriedade `Data` é do tipo `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>` e por isso o Resharper me mostra um aviso dizendo:

> Possible System.InvalidOperationException

E me dá a 'dica' de mudar essa consulta para

```
var source =  from em in query
              let dateTimeOffset = em.Data
              where dateTimeOffset != null
              select new
              {
                  Id = em.UniqueID,
                  Data = dateTimeOffset == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : dateTimeOffset.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm")
              };
```

Me parece que o `let` cria uma variável no meio da consulta, é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`let`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) é usada para definir variáveis em tempo de expressão.

Neste caso:

```
var source =  from em in query
              let dateTimeOffset = em.Data
```

Você está definido uma variável para a declaração `dateTimeOffset`, que é usada mais abaixo:

```
    where dateTimeOffset != null
    select new
    {
        Id = em.UniqueID,
        Data = dateTimeOffset == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : dateTimeOffset.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm")
    };
```

Mas neste caso ela não está sendo muito útil. Ela tem mais utilidade quando o campo é calculado, ou derivado de outros campos. Você poderia muito bem fazer assim:

```
    where em.Data != null
    select new
    {
        Id = em.UniqueID,
        Data = em.Data == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : em.Data.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm")
    };
```

> Me parece que o let cria uma variável no meio da consulta, é isso mesmo? Se for isso, porque o Resharper não indicou fazer `where em.Data != null`?

Porque ele não interpreta a atribuição como redundante, sobretudo porque você usa `select new` pra devolver um objeto de retorno.

Answer (score 2):

É exatamente isto. Quando você vai usar algumas vezes um resultado intermediário, pode ser interessante usar uma variável para manter um "cache" do dado, que é a função normal de toda variável. Inclusive pode evitar algum efeito colateral de executar diversas vezes algum tipo de expressão que pode produzir resultados diferentes.

Claro que este exemplo não é dos melhores porque o ganho é pequeno, mas ele não deixa de ser útil.

Obviamente o escopo dela é a consulta.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).